# Should we pass in Fragment or Activity, when constructing ViewModelProvider within Fragement?

Tags: android

I was wondering, for the following 2 code snippets, which is the recommended way?

### Use Fragment when constructing ViewModelProvider

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ViewModelProvider viewModelProvider = new ViewModelProvider(this);
        tabInfoViewModel = viewModelProvider.get(TabInfoViewModel.class);
    }
```

### Use Activity when constructing ViewModelProvider

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ViewModelProvider viewModelProvider = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity());
        tabInfoViewModel = viewModelProvider.get(TabInfoViewModel.class);
    }
```

Both code are workable. But, which is the "more correct" way?

Answer (score 3):

> It is very common that two or more fragments in an activity need to communicate with each other. This is never trivial as both fragments need to define some interface description, and the owner activity must bind the two together. Moreover, both fragments must handle the case where the other fragment is not yet created or not visible.
>
> This common pain point can be addressed by using ViewModel objects.
>   Imagine a common case of master-detail fragments, where we have a
>   fragment in which the user selects an item from a list and another
>   fragment that displays the contents of the selected item.
>
> These fragments can share a ViewModel using their activity scope to
>   handle this communication.

It will let your `ViewModel` be available between different fragments of same activity. It will be helpful to transfer data between fragments of **same** activity.

```
tabInfoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(TabInfoViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Great answer.  Here's a source from the docs for those interested: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#host-activity

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on @buzzingsilently's answer.
You can also achieve the same behavior of passing in `getActivity()` or `requireActivity()` into the ViewModelProvider by lazily initializing the shared ViewModel instance with the Kotlin property delegate from the `activity-ktx` library.

`val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()`

Make sure you add the dependency for it on your module's build.gradle file.

`implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'`

[Refer to the documentation for further info on sharing ViewModel between fragments.](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#host-activity)